# Play 2.2.x: Running multiple tests in parallel with app local globals

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2, typesafe-activator

I have something like this:

```
object Global extends GlobalSettings {
   def config = Play.current.configuration   

  object repos { 
      val userRepo = new UserDao(config)
      val logRepo = new LogDao(config)
      ....
   }

   ....
}

// In some other file.scala, I use above as `import Global.repos.userRepo`
```

This works fine in general but in my tests I have some tests boot up with different configurations in different specs under the same `play test` but since the Global object is JVM global, the userRepo gets loaded just once per play test. Is there anyway to make the Global object load at the app-local level or manually trigger a reload of the Global object on Play start?

I know I should be using a DI framework but we are not ready to upgrade to Play 2.4 which supports modular dependency injection and it is a much larger refactoring anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly that is a design limitation with the pre 2.4 versions of play, there isn't really any good way around it. There is also internal pieces of play that uses the global play instance, so even if your code didn't then it still wouldn't be safe to run tests that uses WithApplication for example in parallell.

One thing you could do is try to separate things that really needs to interact with play from things that doesn't and run that in regular tests which can then be run in parallell.

For example, put logic outside of controllers in a regular class, make sure it does not touch play.api stuff. If it needs configuration, make it take the individual configuration parameters in the constructor instead of letting them fetch that from the play configuration. Then "wire" stuff elsewhere, in a factory method or in the controllers where you then just call/use the logic.